# Editing windows Registry

Tags: windows, networking

Hai
I want to edit the registry entry of a system from another system using connect network registry.I am getting the system names on my network,but its not possible for me to access the
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE of the system on network.How can I access the registry of the system.

Thank you
Chaithanya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need administrator rights over the remote system that you wish to change.

Comment: How to add administrator rights over remote system
Thank u

Comment: You're going to need admin rights over the target PC to add admin rights, which you wouldn't need if you had them already. You either need physical access to the PC when an administrator is logged in to forge a set of admin credentials for yourself (or just do what you wanted to do there and then), or if the target PC is part of a domain you could get domain administrator access then you'd be able to remote administer the PC. However, I suspect your quest ends here.